# Live-action TV show/movie where kids go into the world of a video game world which looks a lot like World of Warcraft

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Looking for a **live-action** TV show/movie where kids play a computer game which looks a lot like *World of Warcraft*. They can enter this computer world and then the show switches to animated. It would have aired between late '90s and 2010. One thing I remember about the show is that there was a heavy emphasis on their parents' disapproval of them playing computer games, and one kid secretly played the game under his bed sheets. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you remember anything else about this? For example, what was the plot inside the video game world? Would the kids actually enter the video game world or was the show just switching perspective to inside the world to the POV of the characters being played by the kids?

Answer (score 3):

This TV series is probably "Code Lyoko".
[image: Logo]

The kids, when they are in the normal world, they are depicted with hand drawn animation style[image: normal world animation style]

and when they enter the virtual world, they are in a 3D CGI world called Lyoko.[image: virtual world animation style]

Also, the boy wearing glasses almost never enters the virtual world. And the pink-haired girl I think she was an AI that almost never left the virtual world.

Each episode usually develops as this:

- A tower activates in the virtual world.
- The 4 characters in the real world take notice of this (I don't remember how).
- They go through a parkour scene into a supercomputer with inmersive reality sets.
- 3 of the characters go into the virtual world, while the one with glasses stays as "the man in the chair" (like in Spiderman: Homecoming).
- They have some kind of adventure trying to reach the activated tower.
- They deactivate the tower inserting tha password "Lyoko"
- They exit the virtual world and go back in time to fill their places in the real world.
- And usually there it is when the episode ends.

About the plot: The kids are usually in a boarding school. Just before each tower is activated they mess things up either between each other or with somebody else. When they go back in time after each episode, they resolve the mess between themselves and they are able to avoid the complications that come at the beginning of the episode.

**Edit (I didn't see the "live action" part):**

- It might be the sequel of Code Lyoko, Code Lyoko: Evolution, that blends live-action with CGI 3D.

[image: An image of Code Lyoko: Evolution cast, which may help with identification]

Comment: The question indicated that the show was live-action outside of the computer game world.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Now, with the last image you added, the expression 'the man in the chair' looks a bit cruel... In the original series he wasn't paraplegic.

Comment: @4.12.22.4.18.0. Hmm. I'm unfamiliar with either version, to be honest.